# C console program crashes on exit (Access Violation) only when run as an external program in C# using Process.Start()

Tags: c#, c, dll, process, access-violation

I have a console program written in C that uses an unmanaged library (dll) to perform actions with a USB device. It reads and uses the parameters passed to the main function. This program works and exits OK when compiled and executed standalone (in a command line).

Then I have a second program written in C# that should call the first program with some parameters, using the following code:

```
Process runProg = new Process(); 
runProg.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Path\to\my\program.exe";
runProg.StartInfo.Arguments = @"hello123 testing123@test.com";
runProg.Start();
runProg.WaitForExit();
```

It runs the first program which does what it was supposed to do (I checked what the USB device did), but when returning from the program it crashes and shows me the "This program has stopped working" window.

Debugger says:

```
"Unhandled exception at 0x77962EE5 (ntdll.dll) in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x6E650254."
```

What would be different when running the first program from the C# program as opposed to the windows command line that would cause this? Have I forgotten some part?

Is there another way to run the first program? Maybe a way to tell Windows to execute the first program with cmd.exe, not try whatever it is trying to do now that causes this crash? A way to make it functionally the same as if I execute the first program exe manually, which works OK?

Comment: You should find out where the crash happens in `program.exe`.

Comment: Is that *all* your C# program does? It doesn't do anything with USB devices or anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue. Michael's suggestion to find the crash in program.exe made me look at the output in the IDE for program.exe, and I noticed the errors were happening there too, it just wasn't crashing.

Turns out I had a couple of *malloc*'d variables that I forgot to *free*. Fixing that fixed the errors and the crashing in the C# application.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a shot in the dark, but have to tried changing `UseShellExecute` to false?

[MSDN Process Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I tried it now and it does not work, the result is the same.